# Find $f(n)$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i > f(n)) = P(Y>1)$

Tags: probability

> Let $X_1, X_2, ... $ (independend) be a sequence of random variables with $Pois(10$) and $Y \sim N(0,1)$. Find $f(n)$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i > f(n)) = P(Y>1)$

### Approach

$\forall_{j,k} P(X_j = k) = \frac{1}{e^{10}}\frac{10^k}{k!}$
Now let try calculate left and right side
$$P(Y>1) = 1 - P(Y\le 1) = 1- F_Y(1) = 1 - \int_{-\infty}^{1} f_Y(y) dy = 1- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{1} e^{-y^2/2} dy$$
I think that I have to simplify both left and right side and then find $f(n)$ by hand but probably I have taken wrong way to calculate that..

Comment: Are $X_{i}$ independent? Try Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: There is no assumption about that @StanTuwim

Comment: This exercise comes from the old exam. If you are convinced that it is not solvable, it is likely that this additional assumption had been told during the exam. I have updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- This is not a type of question, that can be solved without any "weapon".
- It was designed to check student's knowledge of Central Limit Theorem.
- Assumption of independence is crucial.

> Let $ \ X_{1},X_{2},\cdots, X_{n}, \cdots \ $ be i.i.d $\sim  \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda) \ $ and let $\ Y∼N(0,1) \ $.

Recall that $$\mathrm{D}^2{X_{i}}=\mathbb{E}X_{i}=\lambda.$$

From Central Limit Theorem we know, that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{n}\Bigg( \frac{X_{1}+X_{2}+\cdots+X_{n}}{n} -\lambda \Bigg) \xrightarrow{D} N(0,\lambda). $$
This means that for every $\ c\in \mathbb{R} \ $ we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}\Bigg[\sqrt{n}\Bigg( \frac{X_{1}+X_{2}+\cdots+X_{n}}{n} -\lambda \Bigg) > c  \Bigg] \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}\Big(\sqrt\lambda\cdot Y>c\Big).$$
For $\ c=\sqrt{\lambda} \ $ we simply get
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{P}\Bigg[\Big( X_{1}+X_{2}+\cdots+X_{n}  \Big) > \sqrt{\lambda\cdot n}+n\cdot\lambda  \Bigg] \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}\Big( Y>1\Big).$$

Comment: why if we have $ N(0,\lambda)$ it becomes $ \mathbb{P}\Big(\sqrt\lambda\cdot Y>c\Big)$? I don't understand the reason why you multiply $\sqrt\lambda$ by  $Y$?

Comment: Because $Y\sim N(0,1)$  if and only if $\sqrt\lambda\cdot Y \sim N(0,\lambda)$.

Comment: Right, it is very clear solution. Thanks @Stan .